Typescript: method cannot be added because of index signature?
I have an abstract class like the one below.
export abstract class BaseAPI {
      static readonly [key: string]:
        | ApiCall<unknown> // Defines a single API call with a generic response type
        | { [subKey: string]: ApiCall<unknown> } // Nested API call definitions
        | undefined; // Supports optional static members
        
      // Static method example
      static myStaticMethod(): string {
        return 'This is a static method';
      }
    }

After adding the method in the class, I get this typescript error...
Property 'myStaticMethod' of type '() => string' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ApiCall<unknown> | { [subKey: string]: ApiCall<unknown>; } | undefined'.ts(2411)

How can I handle this?

Please [edit] the code to be a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when we copy and paste it into our own IDEs. Right now there's no declaration for ApiCall so we can't reproduce the issue, and the question risks being closed as needing debugging details.

Ok I will edit the code to have a reproducible example.

I found the solution: I needed to add | (() => string); to the index signature.
An example can be found here: https://playcode.io/2184949.
